xhtml2pdf when works with a parsed table or content div breaks <li> numeration
I need to create pdf document with xhtml2pdf. Everything is great with html, but pdf document breaks the numeration while working with tables or parsed div containers.
pdf
html
I've tried to change that block to many divs and the numeration returned, but it didn't look like something I've needed. But when I changed formatting to the way I want, the numeration disappeared again. Can't understand the reason of this behaviour.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
